# Adding images to Excel that obey both filtering and sorting rules

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am writing an application that generates excel worksheets that might contain images in the first column. (Stackoverflow question trying to solve the same issue from that side is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56940480/adding-images-to-worksheets-that-obey-sorting-and-filtering-rules))

Say I have a worksheet that looks like this (with filtering enabled):

[image]

Where column A includes crudely drawn images of the numerals "1" and "3".

You can also download example worksheets here: https://github.com/dan-kirberger/poi-excel-image-issue/tree/master/examples if you're up for trusting a stranger's files!

When editing the picture properties, you can choose from the following options:
[image]

If I choose "Move and size with cells" then try to sort the sheet, the images don't get sorted (though the rest of the data does):

[image]

Notice the "1" in the image column no longer matches the "Text" column.

If I choose "Move but don't size with cells" then use the filter option, say on column C: 
[image]

Then the images stick around after the rest of their row's data is hidden.

How would I set up these pictures so both filtering AND sorting get applied to the image column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you described in the question seems to be working. Be sure to **resize the cells** based on the size of the image **and then** choose the option "Move and size with cells".

Also I would recommend converting the data into a Table as you can visually see the filter range.

Find an example file in the below link: 
[Filter and Sort Images in Excel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mva0xqiYtMeJSE13N99iLWMvuxIZIFJ3/view?usp=sharing)

**UnFiltered Data Image** 
[image: Un-Filtered Data - Image]

**Filtered Data - Image** 
[image: Filtered Data - Image]

Comment: Thanks! Part of my issue was my real worksheet had different sized rows so sorting would break because the data's new row would not be tall enough.